# different mutex for push and pop

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, boost-thread

I have a class called 'subscribedQueue'. This class receives its data via its subscribed publishers (plural) calling its push method.

In another thread, this class's pop method is called to receive that data.
Thus in a sense this class is a kind of buffer between multiple publishers and their subscribers. For the implementation I have based myself on information found about thread-safe queues [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).

Now my question is twofold:

- **If I would use the same mutex** for pusing and popping values (currently I'm using two differrent mutexes), is it possible for my program to get stuck, waiting on a blocked push?
- If not, how is it possible that both the push and pop methods can get past 'lock(the_same_mutex)'.

My assumption is that, if I would use the same mutex and the program enters the pop method, it will acquire the lock in pop, check if the queue is empty and wait on the condition variable which can never be set in the push method (as the lock is already acquired by pop).

current Code (using two different mutexes):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <queue>
#include "subscriber.h"
#include "pubdata.h"
#ifdef DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#endif

namespace PUBLISHSUBSCRIBE
{
  template<class T>
  class SubscribedQueue: public PUBLISHSUBSCRIBE::Subscriber<T>, private std::queue< PubData<T> >
  {
  public:
    PubData<T>  pop();   //removes the next item from the queue, blocks until the queue is not empty
    void push(const PubData<T> data); //method used by the publisher to push data onto the queue
  private:
    mutable boost::mutex writeMutex_; //only needed for publishing/pushing data
    mutable boost::mutex readMutex_;  //only needed for reading/popping data
    boost::condition_variable notify_;
  };

  template<class T>
  PubData<T> SubscribedQueue<T>::pop() { //Blocks until the queue is not empty
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(readMutex_);
    while(std::queue< PubData<T> >::empty())
      notify_.wait(lock); //block until recieving a notification AND the queue is not empty
    PubData<T> head = std::queue< PubData<T> >::front();
    std::queue< PubData<T> >::pop();
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::string debugOut("pop: " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(head) + " - timestamp: " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(head.timestamp()) + " - from: " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(this) + "\n" );
    std::cout <<debugOut;
#endif
    lock.unlock();
    return head;
  }

  template<class T>
  void SubscribedQueue<T>::push(const PubData<T> data){
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(writeMutex_);
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "published: " << data << std::endl;
#endif
    std::queue< PubData<T> >::push(data);
    lock.unlock();
    notify_.notify_one();
  }
}
#endif //SUBSCRIBEDQUEUE_H
```

[edit] what worries me most is this: I have a boost::condition_variable notify_ on which a 'wait until notified' is performed in pop.
But pop must first lock the mutex, the same mutex that must also be locked in 'push' in order to 'notify' the condition variable.

So won't cause this a deadlock, and why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard library containers aren't thread safe; If you attempt to modify a container from multiple threads simultaneously then *bad things happen*.

If you have a separate mutex for push and pop operations then you don't protect against a simultaneous push and pop from two threads, so you haven't really protected the collection at all.

> My assumption is that, if I would use the same mutex and the program enters the pop method, it will acquire the lock in pop, check if the queue is empty and wait on the condition variable which can never be set in the push method (as the lock is already acquired by pop).

When you wait on the condition variable in pop, wait() *unlocks* the mutex, so a push() while waiting will be able to lock it. push() calls notify_one() and unlocks the mutex by virtue of the scoped_lock going out of scope at the end of the function. Then, when the pop() thread is next scheduled, it will immediately re-lock the mutex and proceed.

Comment: your description was exactly the information I was looking for but could not find myself. thanks for clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must use a single mutex, otherwise say the push has made space for a value and incremented the size, but not finished copying that value into place... the reader could read any manner of garbage.

You don't have to worry about readers and writers deadlocking - the condition variable is designed to arbitrate that situation, allowing the pushing thread to operate while the popping thread waits for notification.

Answer (score 1):

By definition "pop" is the act of **removing** an item from the list.  So if you want to push and pop from the same list from multiple threads, you need to use the same mutex to protect that list.

If you use different mutexes, then that means that these different threads can add/remove items at the same time and so corrupt the list.

When thread A is adding to the list protected by a mutex, then the thread B trying to pop an item off that list, will have to wait until thread A has finished adding the item and has left the lock.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to have the mutexes `mutable` as your code stands right now - they don't seem to be used in any `const` function.

Second, instead of two mutexes, one for read and one for write, you should have just one mutex for **access** to the queue and limit that access to the narowest scope possible, hold the lock not an instruction longer than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use only one Mutex to create a thread-safe queue because you have to ensure that only one thread is accessing the queue at a time (regardless of whether its push or pop).

To answer your questions:
1) With your current implementation of push and pop, there is no possibility of a deadlock (unless you use your mutex elsewhere), because the lock is limited to the scope of push and pop and scoped_lock releases the mutex also in case of an exception.
2) Push and pop can get past the lock if and only if the mutex is currently not locked. Otherwise the thread will be suspended until the locking thread releases the mutex.